# NSF Proposals: numerical citations or author-year?

Tags: citations, nsf

I'm preparing an NSF proposal.  I ordinarily like author-year citations because they seem more scholarly and give the reviewer instant information about who(m) I am citing.  However, multiple people have advised me that it makes the text hard to read, and I've heard that the *most important thing* for NSF proposals is that they are easy to read.

But still- I hate flipping back and forth between text and citations- it seems like that causes a readability problem of a different kind.  At the same time, numerical citations are much more concise and help me make my page limit.

So I am in a bind.  What do you people think?

Comment: I'd use whichever style predominates in your field, or in the journals where you publish. In mathematics, we very rarely use author-year, and if I were reading a proposal that used that style, I'd subconsciously wonder why a psychologist is writing a math proposal.

Comment: or someone doing machine learning.

Comment: @Nate of course in Maths another common citation style is author-initial+year (many papers in Bulletin of AMS and Trans. AMS use this format). For specialist papers quite often author initials + the year allows me to pinpoint the paper without even looking at the bibliography. I think of it as a nice half-way compromise between numerical and full author-year.

Comment: Also, I disagree with the statement that "author-year citations make text hard to read". It may be the case if done poorly (every single citation is parenthetical with author, year). But if you work the author's names into your sentences, there really shouldn't be much loss of readability.

Comment: On that note, natbib and other latex packages have many different \cite commands depending on how you want the reference to flow in the text, so it's easy to do as @WillieWong recommends.

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but this came up on some twitter feeds and science blogs I read a few months ago - with no resolution.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of reference formatting, this is the only paragraph I can find in the [NSF guide](http://www.nsf.gov/pubs/gpg/nsf04_23/nsf04_23.pdf):

> Reference information is required. Each reference must include the
>   names of all authors (in the same sequence in which they appear in the
>   publication), the article and journal title, book title, volume
>   number, page numbers, and year of publication.

Thanks to @Suresh, I misunderstood the meaning of it and I agree that the instruction does not specify either numeric or author-year format.

However, the page limit is 15, all inclusive, numeric system would give you a few more lines at the end. And you don't need to hate flipping back and forth, because the reviewers will do the flipping. However, should you feel so strong against it, call and talk to the grant program manager or contact person and ask if you can use your preferred system.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the statement. It's not that references should appear in the order in which they were cited. It's that the list of authors in the bibliographic reference should reflect the author order in the original publication being cited. This is orthogonal to whether you use author-year OR numerical citation mode. Your point about the page limit is a valid one though: numerical references are more compact.

Comment: @Suresh, many thanks and I agreed. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have reviewed many thousands of NSF proposals (and written a few dozen, many funded) and strongly recommend numerical. You should note that even the NSF Guide uses numerical (for footnotes).

Reviewers tend to like the following order: Author(s) Journal Volume Pages Year

Make sure you use first and last pages: ie 2311-2318 not 2311-18 which is ambiguous

You may find EndNote or Papers the way to go for references.

Answer (score 0):

My advisor actually gave me a copy of the proposal for an NSF grant that funded some of my research, it had numerical citations. But also note that this is the style most commonly used in my field (machine learning).